# Windows Phone show ConnectionSettingsTask and back

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working on a windows phone app right now.

In the app, I am handling an exception in page 1, that when there is no wifi connection, it will pop a XNA messagebox, user can choose to open the WIFI settings page. I have the following code:

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();

connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;

connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

But the problem with this is, when user hit `back key` in the `wifi settings` page, they will be navigate back to page 1, which has a loading problem and can not display the proper content. In this case, I would like user to directly go to another page, call it page 2.

Is that possible?  Thank you

++++++++++++++Update

Is there are way to customize the back key functionality when showing the XNA messagebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about XNA coding much, but I do know that if you return from wifi connection page to your app, the `OnNavigatedTo` function is invoked. Try setting out your flow of code according to the application flow. If there is some code you have executed at the constructor, shift it to `OnNavigatedTo` and vice-verse, which may solve your problem. Also if you want to shift to another page, do it in the same function `(OnNavigatedTo)` itself. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the navigation behavior: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx

However it is recommended to merge the two pages together (hide loading bar and show main page) as you will have less problems...

Answer (score 0):

why not handle this code in the IsNetworkAvailable check? that way you'l avoid the exception altogether